# Could not instantiate listener org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.ApplicationListener

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to setup dataimportscheduler for my index, when I add:

```
  <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.ApplicationListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
```

to my webdefault.xml and run start.jar, I get:

```
2012-06-30 11:04:52.959:INFO::Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2012-06-30 11:04:53.457:INFO::jetty-6.1-SNAPSHOT
2012-06-30 11:04:53.953:WARN::Could not instantiate listener org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.ApplicationListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.scheduler.ApplicationListener
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.loadClass(ContextHandler.java:1102)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initListener(WebXmlConfiguration.java:630)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initWebXmlElement(WebXmlConfiguration.java:368)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.initialize(WebXmlConfiguration.java:289)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configure(WebXmlConfiguration.java:222)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebXmlConfiguration.configureDefaults(WebXmlConfiguration.java:162)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1262)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
        at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
        at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:441)
        at org.mortbay.start.Main.main(Main.java:119)
```

I added:

```
<lib dir="../../dist/" regex="apache-solr-dataimportscheduler-1.0.jar" />
```

to solrconfig.xml (have successfully loaded some other libraries this way), but it doesn't change anything, based on times shown in error message and log files it seems that webdefault.xml is loaded before solrconfig.xml.

I loaded apache-solr-dataimportscheduler-1.0.jar with -cp option of java in command-line, but didn't work.

Any idea what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question a few days ago.  Please check it out.
[Solr DataImportHandler configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097931/solr-dataimporthandler-configuration/11102507#11102507)

If that does not help, the other option is to copy this jar to solr.war's web-inf\lib folder.  This can be done in the jetty's exploded folder under webapps...

Comment: Unfortunately your answer to that question doesn't help in my case, as I mentioned above, I've successfully loaded libraries before (like mysql-connector-java) so it shouldn't be about the location of jar file.
Based on timestamps on log files and error messages it's obvious that webdefault.xml is loading before solrconfig.xml so loading libraries in solrconfig.xml doesn't help, I'l check web-inf/lib thing and let you know if it works.

Comment: @Sassan Thanks for pointing this out. I altered the wiki page so that it includes all needed info for deploying DIHScheduler.

Comment: Welcome, There's another problem with dataimport-schedule configuration that I couldn't find its solution in the documentation, that's how can one configure dataimport-scedule so that it authenticate itself for http calls, I made a question for it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11274525/unauthorized-dataimport-scheduler-calls), it'd be great if you could let me know if there's a solution.

Comment: It's not included because Solr is usually deployed internally, meaning it's not exposed outside your intranet. That's because it is rarely used by end users directly, there's usually some application that uses Solr as search service and represents interface between end user and Solr.