# Unauthorized dataimport-scheduler calls

Tags: solr, dataimporthandler

I'm trying to setup an dataimport-scheduler for solr, everything's working and the deltaimport url is called every 30 minutes, the only problem is I'm using jetty and activated authentication in jetty.xml so the dataimport_scheduler gets:

```
<index update process> Response message                        Unauthorized
```

(saw in log file), How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you importing data from a db? Where did you add authentication? Is it http basic auth?

Comment: @javanna: yes, importing from a db and yes it's http basic authentication added in jetty.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DataImportScheduler` needs to have access to your solr/dataimport url via http. The error you see in the log file is because of the authentication you added. As far as I know the `DataImportScheduler` doesn't support authentication out of the box, but it should be easy to add it to the code.

Unfortunately it doesn't use `http-client`, which would have made things a bit easier and flexible I guess, but you can have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java) answer to find out how to add http basic authentication to http calls made through the `HttpURLConnection` class.